# query inside a pdo while loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi all I think I designed my pdo mysql class rather badly, as I'm not able to put a query inside a while loop of another query because the new query inside the loop wipes out the old one, is there an easy way to fix this?

I'm too used to the really old style of php/mysql where you make a query, then assign that query inside the fetch($query) which you don't do with PDO. This has me in a muddle and it's been bugging me for too long.

My Code cut to the relevant parts

```
class mysql
{
    // the query counter
    public $counter = 0;

    // the database connection
    public $database;

    // statement handler
    public $STH;

    // store all the queries for debugging
    public $queries = '';

    public function __construct($database_host, $database_username, $database_password, $database_db)
    {
        $options = array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
        ); 
        $this->database = new PDO("mysql:host=$database_host;dbname=$database_db", $database_username, $database_password, $options);  
        $this->database->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    }

    // A plain query
    public function pquery($sql, $page = NULL)
    {
        global $core;

        try
        {
            $this->STH = $this->database->prepare($sql);  

            $this->counter++;

            $this->queries .= "<br />$sql";

            return $this->STH->execute();
        }

        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $core->message("Something went wrong. The admin will be notified and punished muhahaha for I am an evil overlord...I'm sure I will be fixed soon.", NULL, 1);
            $this->pdo_error($e->getMessage(), $page, $sql);
        }
    }

    // the main sql query function
    public function sqlquery($sql, $objects = array(), $page = NULL, $referrer = NULL)
    {
        global $core;

        try
        {
            $this->STH = $this->database->prepare($sql);

            foreach($objects as $k=>$p)
            {
                // +1 is needed as arrays start at 0 where as ? placeholders start at 1 in PDO
                if(is_numeric($p))
                {
                    // we need to do this or else decimals always seem to end up 'x.00', pdo has no decimal check, odd
                    if ($this->contains_decimal($p) == true)
                    {
                        $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, $p, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, (int)$p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, $p, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                }
            }

            $this->counter++;

            $this->queries .= "<br />$sql";

            return $this->STH->execute();
        }

        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $core->message("Something went wrong. The admin will be notified and punished muhahaha for I am an evil overlord...I'm sure I will be fixed soon.", NULL, 1);
            $this->pdo_error($e->getMessage(), $page, $sql, $referrer);
        }
    }

    public function fetch()
    {
        $this->STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        return $this->STH->fetch();
    }
```

Comment: You need to execute each different statement..

Comment: @Naruto <- This. He has the right answer. The EXECUTE statement is outside your foreach loop.

Comment: So just execute it, then loop through the results separately?

Comment: @LiamDawe If you want to catch all the results from multiple statements you will have to make sure you push them into an array or something to hold onto them so they don't overwrite each other.